# Python - Extracting data from the table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from the table and that I accessed by using beautiful soup library. I get the table as html but I am strugling to extract data in consumable form since the table itself has two columns with headers in first and values in second.

Here is my code:

```
html = browser.html
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", {"id":"productDetails_techSpec_section_1"})
table
```

Results of printing table:

```
"<table class="a-keyvalue prodDetTable" id="productDetails_techSpec_section_1" role="presentation">
<tbody><tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                    Part Number 
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              3885SD
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                  Item Weight
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              1.83 pounds
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                  Product Dimensions
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              9 x 6 x 3.5 inches
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                  Item model number
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              3885SD
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                  Item Package Quantity
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              1
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                  Number of Handles
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              1
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                  Batteries Included?
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              No
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
                  Batteries Required?
                </th>
<td class="a-size-base">
              No
            </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>"
```

I tried using this line of code to access each header and data point:

```
headings = [table.get_text() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]
print(headings)
```

And this is the response i get:

```
['\n\n\n                  \tPart Number\t\n                \n\n              3885SD\n            \n\n\n\n                  Item Weight\n                \n\n              1.83 pounds\n            \n\n\n\n                  Product Dimensions\n                \n\n              9 x 6 x 3.5 inches\n            \n\n\n\n                  Item model number\n                \n\n              3885SD\n            \n\n\n\n                  Item Package Quantity\n                \n\n              1\n            \n\n\n\n                  Number of Handles\n                \n\n              1\n            \n\n\n\n                  Batteries Included?\n                \n\n              No\n            \n\n\n\n                  Batteries Required?\n                \n\n              No\n            \n\n']
```

I have been researching different approaches to get this data into `pandas dataframe` and this is the closes i got so far. 
My questions is how do i get this data into data frame where my headers and values would be like example below?

[image]

Comment: Surely this should be `headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]`, right? `table.get_text()` looks wrong within the list comprehension.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel - hi, thank you for your response. I have tried that too and i get this as results: ['\n                  \tPart Number\t\n                ']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to transpose values in table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser') # data is your table from question

rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    rows.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('th, td')])

rows = [*zip(*rows)]    # transpose values

for row in rows:
    print(''.join(r'{: <25}'.format(d) for d in row))
```

Prints:

```
Part Number              Item Weight              Product Dimensions       Item model number        Item Package Quantity    Number of Handles        Batteries Included?      Batteries Required?      
3885SD                   1.83 pounds              9 x 6 x 3.5 inches       3885SD                   1                        1                        No                       No
```

Answer (score 2):

- [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) - Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.

**Ex.**

```
 import pandas as pd

html = """<table class="a-keyvalue prodDetTable" id="productDetails_techSpec_section_1" role="presentation">
 <tbody><tr><th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Part Number </th>
 <td class="a-size-base">3885SD</td></tr><tr>
 <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
 Item Weight</th><td class="a-size-base">1.83 pounds</td></tr>
 <tr><th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Product Dimensions</th>
 <td class="a-size-base">9 x 6 x 3.5 inches</td>
 </tr><tr><th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Item model number</th>
 <td class="a-size-base">3885SD</td></tr>
 <tr><th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Item Package Quantity
 </th><td class="a-size-base">1</td></tr><tr>
 <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Number of Handles
 </th><td class="a-size-base">1</td></tr><tr>
 <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Batteries Included?
 </th><td class="a-size-base">No</td></tr><tr>
 <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
  Batteries Required?</th><td class="a-size-base">No</td></tr></tbody></table>"""

#read table data
df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
cols = df[0]
vals = df[1]

table = pd.DataFrame(vals).T
#reset columns name
table.columns = cols
print(table)
```

**O/P:**

```
0 Part Number  Item Weight  Product Dimensions Item model number Item Package Quantity Number of Handles Batteries Included? Batteries Required?
1      3885SD  1.83 pounds  9 x 6 x 3.5 inches            3885SD                     1                 1                  No                  No
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Create the function to parste the table:

```
def parse_table(table):
    """ Get data from table """
    return [
        [cell.get_text().strip() for cell in row.find_all(['th', 'td'])]
           for row in table.find_all('tr')
    ]
```

Then create new table by using the function and convert the table into panda dataframe:

```
new_table = parse_table(table)
df = pd.DataFrame(new_table)
df =df.T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df
```